# How to convert a HyperSpectral image or an image with many bands in TFRecord format?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, dataset, tfrecord

I've been trying to use a hyperspectral image dataset that was in .mat files. I found that using the *scipy* library with its *loadmat* function I can load the hyperspectral images and selecting some bands to see them as an RGB.

```
    def RGBread(image):   
      images = loadmat(image).get('new_image')
      return abs(images[:,:,(12,6,4)])
    def SIread(image):
      images = loadmat(image).get('new_image')
      return abs(images[:,:,:])
```

After trying to implement the pix2pix architecture I found an unexpected error. When passing the list of the names of the dataset files by a function that is responsible for load the data(which are still .mat files), Tensor Flow does not have a direct method for this reading or coding, so I get these data with my RGBread and SIread method and then I turned them into tensors.

```
    def load_image(filename, augment=True): 

      inimg = tf.cast( tf.convert_to_tensor(RGBread(ImagePATH+'/'+filename)
             ,dtype=tf.float32),tf.float32)[...,:3]
      tgimg = tf.cast( tf.convert_to_tensor(SIread(ImagePATH+'/'+filename)
             ,dtype=tf.float32),tf.float32)[...,:12]

      inimg, tgimg = resize(inimg, tgimg,IMG_HEIGH,IMG_WIDTH)

      if augment:
        inimg, tgimg = random_jitter(inimg, tgimg)

      return inimg, tgimg
```

When loading an image with the load_image method, using the name and path of a single .mat file (a hyperspectral image) of my dataset as argument of my function the method worked perfectly.

```
plt.imshow(load_train_image(tr_urls[1])[0])
```

The problem started when I created my dataSet tensor, because my RGBread function does not receive a tensor as a parameter since *loadmat('.mat')* expects a string. Having the following error.

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tr_urls)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(load_train_image,
                num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Tensor
```

After reading a lot about reading .mat files I found a user who recommended passing the data to TFrecord format. I've been trying to do it but I couldn't. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

Rasterio may be useful here.

https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

It can read hyperspectral .tif which can be passed to tf.data using a tf.keras data-generator. It may be a bit slow and perhaps should be done before training rather than at runtime.

An alternative is to ask whether you need the geotiff metadata. If not, you can preprocess and save as numpy arrays for tfrecords.

Comment: Thank you, but I solved my problem with tf.keras.Sequential, this library allow me create a DataGenerator.